# how to populate django models randomly

Tags: django

I am following a tutorial online for Django. The presenter loads in random data as follows:

```
for i in xrange(100): Vote(link = Link.objects.order_by('?')[0],voter=a).save()
```

From what I could understand, it goes from 0 to 100 and creates a new vote. The vote object has a link object. I don't understand what the order_by('?') means.

Here is the model.py file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import Count

class LinkVoteCountManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(LinkVoteCountManager, self).get_query_set().annotate(
            votes=Count('vote')).order_by("-votes")

class Link(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("Headline", max_length=100)
    submitter = models.ForeignKey(User)
    submitted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    rank_score = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    url = models.URLField("URL", max_length=250, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    with_votes = LinkVoteCountManager()
    objects = models.Manager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Vote(models.Model):
    voter = models.ForeignKey(User)
    link = models.ForeignKey(Link)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s voted %s" %(self.voter.username, self.link.title)
```

Comment: `order_by('?')` means return a random record from the database table every time the query is run.

Comment: Right, it's a database-level randomization rather than using Python to generate random numbers. Note that there's no guarantee at all against returning the same `Link` instance twice. Which may be perfectly fine depending on the use case.